# Json error in android

Tags: php, android, json

I have an android mobile application that will use  a php file called "`login.php`" to connect to a database that contains username and password , the result of the php file is in `JSON` format and this is how it looks : `{"username":"mounzer","password":"yaghi"}`
As for the mobile application this is the code :

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);         
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // defaultHttpClient
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.38/mobileappd/Login.php");

    username=user.getText().toString();
    password=pass.getText().toString();

    try {
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",username));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200) {
            entity=response.getEntity();    

            if(entity !=null) {
                InputStream instream=entity.getContent();
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
                String retUser=jsonResponse.getString("username");
                String retPass=jsonResponse.getString("password");

                if(username.equals(retUser) && password.equals(retPass)) {

                    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("logindetails",0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor spedit=sp.edit();
                    spedit.putString("user",username);
                    spedit.putString("pass", password);
                    spedit.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Succesfully connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Well it's giving me the following error : 
"`org.json.JSONException:value DOCTYPE of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONobject`"   Can someone tell where is the error in the code.

Comment: can you submit more of the error log you are getting please

Answer (score 0):

**Here The error message says**:

```
Value `<!DOCTYPE` of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

If it is `<!DOCTYPE` then it isn't `{"username":….`

You need to figure out exactly what request is being made and why the server is returning an HTML document.

Check your server logs. It might be an error document.

Answer (score 0):

Check the result returned from the link you are calling, I think it is returning the html page since it says "value DOCTYPE can't be converted to JSONOBject". so check the response you are getting from calling that link